# Google maps создание пользовательского слоя (google.maps.OverlayView) с повторениями

Tags: google-maps-api

Необходимо создать пользовательский слой google.maps.OverlayView с отображением повторений аналогично как работает google maps Polygon.Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с данной темой. Это можно сделать с помощью Overlay Map Types
документация и описание https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes